# Best Python API for sending Bitcoins from a Multi-Sig wallet

Tags: transactions, api, python

I want to create a multi-sig wallet which I can broadcast transactions through an API. I would like a wallet with a permanent public address not one that changes every time I run the code. I was going to use Blocktrail but some of their API features are broken. Does anyone know any other good API`s?

Some context as to what I want to do: automate the sending of coins to certain addresses at a certain time each week.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pyCoin can be useful for your purpose?
https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin/blob/master/COMMAND-LINE-TOOLS.md